# JavaScript Array: How to get indexes of `false` values that are adjascent to a wrapped-around sequence of `true` values?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given an array in JavaScript that:

- is of unknown length greater than 0,
- contains only boolean values,
- contains an unknown number of `true` and `false` values, where
- `true` values always occur in one continuous set, but
- the continuous set of `true` values may "wrap around" the array, and
- there is always at least one `true` in the array

how does one write a JavaScript function that returns the indexes of the two `false` values (in any order) that are immediately "adjacent" to the full set of `true` values?

Consider the following examples, where carrots (^) denote the indexes I would like returned:

```
[true, true, false, false, false, true];
               ^             ^

[false, false, true, true, true, false, false]
          ^                        ^

[true, true, true, false, false, false, false, false]
                     ^                           ^

[false, false, false, true, true]
   ^             ^

[true, false, false, false, false]
         ^                    ^

[false, false, true, false, false, false]
          ^            ^
```

Apart from the visual examples above, I've been unable to construct the logic within JavaScript.

Comment: If you were asked how to do it by hand, how would you do it? That might give you a start on the logic you could apply (it's better if you learn, rather than getting a ready-made answer). _Hint: don't overthink. The answer is pretty simple_

Comment: I was also going to ask if you've attempt to draw this out as a simple diagram (using any shapes you want to).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been very interesting and educational to see the different ways to solve such a problem. Here's what made sense to me.

```
function getEnds(a) {
  // Return an empty array if there are no falses.
  if (a.indexOf(false) == -1) {
    return [];
  }

  // Obtain ends based on array length, number of trues,
  // and the delta from beginning of array to first true in sequence.
  const length = a.length,
      numTrues = a.filter(Boolean).length,
      delta = a[0] ? a.lastIndexOf(false)+1 : a.indexOf(true),
      end1 = (delta + length-1) % length;
      end2 = (delta + numTrues) % length;      

  // If both ends are the same, return one, otherwise return both.
  return end1 == end2 ? [end1] : [end1, end2];
}
```

Tests:

```
console.log(getEnds([false, false, true, true, true, false, false])); // [1, 5]
console.log(getEnds([true, true, true, false, false, false, false, false])); // [7, 3]
console.log(getEnds([false, false, false, true, true])); // [2, 0]
console.log(getEnds([true, false, false, false, false])); // [4, 1]
console.log(getEnds([false, false, true, false, false, false])); // [1, 3]
console.log(getEnds([true, true, true])); // [ ]
console.log(getEnds([true, false, true])); // [1]
console.log(getEnds([false, true, false])); // [0, 2]
console.log(getEnds([true, true])); // [ ]
console.log(getEnds([true])); // [ ]
```

Comment: This is worse than all the other answers so far in readability, performance, and best practices. For example, that `while` loop is especially bad given that it repeatedly uses `.slice()` and `.indexOf()` and then, to really bring the pain, also rotates the original array.

Comment: Thanks @Ouroborus. Sarcasm aside, I appreciate the insight. The loop and rotating the original array were actually entirely unnecessary. I've simplified it accordingly. What I like about this approach is that it requires relatively little handling of logic to account for various scenarios, instead relying on math for the core functionality. Then again, I expect the use of filter and modulus to be slower than using simple logic, even if I find it more concise in terms of readability. Is there anything else you'd improve if you were going to take this general approach?

Comment: I think you've made a huge improvement here. The remaining suggestions are mostly cosmetic: Change `var` to `const`, move `e1`, `e2` up into the variable assignments (I recognize you did it that way to make the comment stand out), and give the variables names that a bit less cryptic and you'll have a serviceable solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use below function to get start and end of false

```js
function getIndexes(arr) {
  var a = arr.indexOf(true);
  var start;
  var end;
  if(a==0)
  {
    start=arr.indexOf(false);
    var temp=arr.indexOf(true,start);
    if(temp==-1){
    end=arr.length-1;
    }
    else{
    end=temp-1;
    }
  }
  else{
    start=a-1;
    var temp=arr.indexOf(false,a);
    if(temp==-1){
    start=0
    end=a-1
    }
    else{
    end=temp
    }
    }
  return [start,end]
}
```

Comment: Great! Thank you. This does seem to work with just a little extra logic added to handle edge cases like when there is zero or one `false` values to avoid `-1` from being returned (which is probably fine). I like this relatively simple approach. I would say the answer would be great if it had a bit more explanation with it, either in the description or within the code.

Answer (score 1):

Only one of the two spans can wrap if any does. Which one might wrap can be determined by checking the first element. Search for the ends of the span that definitely doesn't wrap. Compute the ends of the span we actually want from that.

```js
const findFalseSegment = (arr) => {
  const last = arr.length-1;
  let start, end;
  // If the first element is true, the span of false elements doesn't wrap
  if(arr[0]) {
    start = arr.indexOf(false, 1);
    if(start < 0) return {start: NaN, end: NaN};
    end = arr.indexOf(true, start + 1) - 1;
    if(end < 0) end = last;
    return {start, end};
  }
  // If the first element is false, the span of false elements might wrap
  // Find the span of true elements instead and compute the span of false 
  // elements from that.
  start = arr.indexOf(true, 1);
  if(start < 0) return {start: NaN, end: NaN};
  end = arr.indexOf(false, start + 1) - 1;
  if(end < 0) end = last;
  return {
    start: end == last ? 0 : end + 1, 
    end: start == 0 ? last : start - 1,
  };
};
```

---

Edit: It occurred to me that the main `if` can be rolled into the rest of the code without impacting performance though it does make it more difficult to comment.

```js
const findFalseSegment = (arr) => {
  const last = arr.length-1;
  const start = arr.indexOf(!arr[0], 1);
  if(start < 0) return {start: NaN, end: NaN};
  let end = arr.indexOf(arr[0], start + 1) - 1;
  if(end < 0) end = last;
  return arr[0] ? { start, end } : {
    start: end == last ? 0 : end + 1, 
    end: start == 0 ? last : start - 1,
  };
};
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining the logic for this, both in the description and within the code. That allows for a good understanding of how you're going about it. It seems to fail on: `[true, true, true, false, false, false, false, false]` and `[false, false, false, true, true]` and `[true, false, false, false, false]` so it's likely just a matter of dealing with scenarios where no wrapping occurs.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I get for not testing. The strategy I outlined is sound but my implementation missed an edge-case as well as had a bug. I've made the necessary fixes.

Comment: Great - thanks @Ouroborus for making those corrections. It seems to work great now. What I like about this is that it's likely quite performant, being based on simple comparisons. What I don't love is the amount of code it takes to handle each possible scenario via if/then logic throughout the code. But again, as I said that's also what I would expect to make it performant.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function which returns an array with the two indexes:

```
function foo(arr) {
    let answers = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] && arr[i - 1] === false) {
        answers.push(i - 1);
    } else if (arr[i] && arr[i + 1] === false) {
        answers.push(i + 1)
    }
  }
  if (arr[0] !== arr[arr.length - 1]) {
    if (arr[0]) {
        answers.push(arr.length - 1)
    } else {
        answers.push(0);
    }
  }
  return answers;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It seems to fail on `[false, false, true, false, false, false]` and `[false, true, false]`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `forEach` to try to find first-false and last-false based on loop and in some cases where the true values are either on the start or on the end of the array you need to find last-false by using indexOf and lastIndexOf.

```js
function f(data) {
  let ft, lt, ff, lf

  data.forEach((e, i, a) => {
    if (e) ft = i

    if (!e && (a[i - 1] || a[i + 1])) {
      if (!ff && i != ff) ff = i
      else lf = i
    }
  })

  if (!lf) {
    if (!data[data.length - 1]) lf = data.lastIndexOf(false)
    else lf = data.indexOf(false)
  }

  return [ff, lf];
}

const cases = [
    [true, true, false, false, false, true],
  [false, false, true, true, true, false, false],
  [true, true, true, false, false, false, false, false],
  [false, false, false, true, true],
  [true, false, false, false, false],
  [false, false, true, false, false, false]
]

cases.forEach(c => console.log(JSON.stringify(f(c))))
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this. It seems to fail on `[false, true, false]`. I would suggest the remedy because I suspect it's simple, but I have a bit of a hard time understanding the logic due to the variables being so abbreviated.